# Calling cloud endpoint library from a client

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I created `Google Cloud endpoint` library and follow the instructions from [Calling Google Apis from Android](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-android)

But I'm not able to use my endpoints. I created a new project in **Android Studio**
and copy all the dependencies  in `gradle.build` But When I run the project I see following errors.

**Java Compiler:**

```
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\22.0\3564ef3803de51fb0530a8377ec6100b33b0d073\guava-22.0.jar

   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.


 Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete


   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
```

**Android Issue:**

```
 Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Collection com.google.common.collect.BiMap.values()
 Message{kind=ERROR, text=Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Collection com.google.common.collect.BiMap.values(), sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

  Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean com.google.common.base.Predicate.test(java.lang.Object)
  Message{kind=ERROR, text=Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean com.google.common.base.Predicate.test(java.lang.Object), sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My `MainActivity.java` is empty right now. 
Here is my `gradle.build`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.azeem.endpointtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Add the Google API client library.
    implementation(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.21.0') {
        // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }

    // Add the Android extensions for the Google API client library.
    // This will automatically include play services as long as you have download that library
    // from the Android SDK manager.
    // Add the Android extensions for the Google API client library.
    implementation(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android',
            version: '1.21.0')
            {
                // Exclude play services, since we're not using this yet.
                exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services', module: 'google-play-services')
            }

    // END Google APIs


    // The following client libraries make HTTP/JSON on Android easier.

    // Android extensions for Google HTTP Client.
    implementation(group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android',
            version: '1.21.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }

    // This is used by the Google HTTP client library.
    implementation(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '22.0')

    implementation files('libs/endpointapi-v1-1.23.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

In my whole Api I don't need to make any **authenticated calls** So, please let me know what library is not required so I removed. I want to **implement** mini library that are necessary. And please let me know why I'm facing this error.

Comment: Looks like you're using a library that requires API level 24 or higher, and your min SDK level is 15.  If you cannot raise your minimum SDK version, then you will not be able to use that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself, Only two dependencies are required for this.
One is `google-api-client-android` and the other is `Your_endpoint_lib`

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0';
implementation files('libs/endpointapi-v1-1.23.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```